# What should I pass as allocator to a std::hash_map?

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

I have created a little class and am trying to use it as the data in an STL `hash_map`. Lots of searching has got me as far as knowing I need to add stuff as the Allocator, but so far I have seen no examples of how to use the default allocators in STL in my class. Could someone help and show me please? I've put a reduced version of my class below.

```
class cwVariable {

public:
    cwVariable();
    template <typename T>
    cwVariable(T value)
    {
        stash = new byte[sizeof(T)];
        memcpy(stash, &value, sizeof(T));
    }

    template <typename T>
    void set(T value)
    {
        if (stash != 0) {
            memcpy(stash, &value, sizeof(T));
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    T get()
    {
        T out;
        memcpy(&out, stash, sizeof(T));
        return out;
    }
    ~cwVariable();
private:
    void * stash = 0;
};


cwVariable::~cwVariable() {
    delete stash;
}
```

For completeness: I'm using the Arduino 1.6.4 toolchain, the STL from a port for Arduino and targetting an Arduino Mega 2560. Using the Visual Micro add-in for Visual Studio 2012.

Added later:
My real code handles more than above, but just C type string pointers, not String. The trail started when I added

```
std::hash_map<const char*, cwVariable> months;
```

to my code and got the output

```
cwVar.cpp.o:In function `std::hash_map<char const*, cwVariable, std::hash<char const*>,
std::equal_to<char const*>, std::allocator<cwVariable> >::operator[](char const* const&)'
stl_hash_map.h:cwVariable()' 
collect2.exe*:error: ld returned 1 exit status as the error.
```

This made me research more and got me worried about allocators.

Comment: Why don't you make `stash` a `T *`? Your code would be shorter and would work correctly on more types.

Comment: Fyi, this is a recipe for disaster for any non-trivial type used in creating `cwVariable` objects from. Will it work for `int`,  `double`, and `struct Point { int x, y; };` ? Sure. Will it work for `std::string` and `std::vector<>`? Um. not really. There are other potential issues (ex: create with `int`, then `set` with `double` has segfault written all over it on most platforms) that you certainly need to be aware of going into this.

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the allocator?

Comment: @AlanStokes - It's an XY problem. The questioner thinks that that is the problem, so that's what he/she asked about.

Comment: @DavidHammen Probably - although they might just want `stash` to be allocated by the map's allocator. (My advice would be "don't".)

Comment: Thank you all, David Hammen calls me right though, the question might not be the right one due to gross ignorance! C++ is a new language to me. My real code handles more than above, but just C type string pointers, not String. The trail started when I added std::hash_map<const char*, cwVariable> months; to my code and got cwVar.cpp.o:In function `std::hash_map<char const*, cwVariable, std::hash<char const*>, std::equal_to<char const*>, std::allocator<cwVariable> >::operator[](char const* const&)'
stl_hash_map.h:cwVariable()'
collect2.exe*:error: ld returned 1 exit status
 as the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your error using the gcc `<ext/hash_map>` implementation of the STL hash map. The hash map was one of the parts of the original STL that never made it into the C++ standard library. (There is no such thing as `std::hash_map`, at least not officially. C++11 does however offer `std::unordered_map`, which is similar to the STL hash map.) Another problem is that you are using Arduino. There are many different ports of the STL to Arduino, most of which aren't quite standard.

Comment: Yes, I was getting afeared that might be the case @davidhammen, I should hunt out some of the other ports and see what results.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an allocator. Those are for when you are doing your own memory management (e.g., a memory pool). What you do need, and what your class does not have, is a working deep copy constructor. Your class instead has the freebie shallow copy constructor. This will copy the pointer rather than the contents of the pointer.

As is, your class doesn't contain the necessarily information to know how to copy construct an instance. One way to solve this would be to store the size of the allocated type as a data member. The copy constructor will allocate a `stash` of the right size and `memcpy` the source stash to the new stash of the new instance.

A much better approach would be to make the entire class a class template, and this goes after an underlying problem with your design. Your use of `void*` and `memcpy` are a recipe for future problems. As is, your class works for [POD classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType), but not much else.

If you templatize the entire class and change `void* stash` to `T stash`, the freebie copy constructor is exactly what you want. If you change the `void* stash` to `T* stash`, you will have to provide a copy constructor, but it's rather simple. In both cases, your get and set member functions are trivial, and your code is much more generic than is your current `void* stash` / `memcpy` implementation.

Comment: I'll have to work to understand this, but pain is ignorance leaving the body... Will be back back after thunking.

Comment: Yes, using your ideas @davidhammen, and others, I can see the advantage of a class template. My full stuff also handles char arrays (null strings) - I cannot see how to add per type exceptions to a template (yet) will try searching on that. I have seen something.. I'm currently only string to stash PODs and null term strings. But hash_map still hates it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using your class as a data type in hash_map does not require you to have an allocator. You only need allocator if you want to implement specific allocation policy for your map.

Comment: Simply using the class as the data type crashes the linker, see my comment to my own question above.